# How do you merge two different arrays of objects of the same size?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, array-merge

I'm attempting to merge the following two objects into one. I want it to be an array of objects with values {companyType, companyName, companyLocation, companyPhone, score} but everything I've tried doesn't merge the objects properly. The actual objects are much larger but they are the same exact size. So I need something that deals with many objects in an array not just two items per array.

```
let company_details = [{companyType: 'Carrier',
                        companyName: 'Auto',
                        companyLocation: 'San Diego, CA',
                        companyPhone: '(123) 456-7890' },
                       {companyType: 'Dealer',
                        companyName: 'Car',
                        companyLocation: 'Indianapolis, IN',
                        companyPhone: '(234) 567-8901' }]

let scoreArr= [{score: 'Your Rating: None'},
               {score: 'Your Rating: Positive'}]
```

Comment: Is there a formal relation between the arrays?

Comment: Python has a built in function for this called zip. https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: Your question as posed is too ambiguous for me to understand in order to answer it.  Please re-phrase it to include the *expected result.*

Comment: @MikeRobinson The way the question is asked and the data looks like, I expect Kllicks asks for an element wise merge of these arrays, where the objects in each element are merged into one object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach takes an array of same length arrays and merge the objects at every index.

Methods used:

- [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for reducing a set of arrays and getting a single array.
- [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for mapping objects with an object from the left side of reduce `a` and an object from the right side of reduce `b` at the same index.
- [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for cloning an object as object literal. The order defines the value of same named properties, the last winns.

The result is an array of objects.

```js
let companies = [{ companyType: 'Carrier', companyName: 'Auto', companyLocation: 'San Diego, CA', companyPhone: '(123) 456-7890' }, { companyType: 'Dealer', companyName: 'Car', companyLocation: 'Indianapolis, IN', companyPhone: '(234) 567-8901' }],
    scores = [{ score: 'Your Rating: None' }, { score: 'Your Rating: Positive' }],
    merged = [companies, scores].reduce((a, b) => a.map((o, i) => ({ ...o, ...b[i] })));

console.log(merged);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: While "I think you're definitely going down the right path," Nina, may I suggest that you re-write your answer to be more clear?  For instance, tell the poor soul what `reduce` does.  And, how about maybe an alternate explanation that uses a simple `for`-loop?  Just a thought ...

Answer (score 0):

Some functional languages have very good list comprehension tools, for instance Haskell's zipWith. It takes two lists and applies a bivariate function to each set of elements.

However, we can easily implement it with arrow functions in present JS (ES6):

```
const zipWith = f => xs => ys => xs.map((x, i) => f(x, ys[i]));
```

In case you are not used to arrow function syntax: *zipWith* is a function with three parameters, a function *f*, and arrays *xs* and *ys*.

We use then *map*, a built in method of Array. It takes a function as argument and applies each element of *xs* to it. Hence the second arrow function in the argument of map. When *map* receives a bivariate function, it provides the array index corresponding to each element as second argument, here *i*.

We provide now *x* an element of *xs* as first argument to our provided function *f*. The second argument is the corresponding element of the other array `ys[i]`.

With the *zipWith* function we need another function to merge those objects in your array. The *Object.assign* method helps here:

```
const mergerFun = (a, b) => Object.assign({}, a, b)
```

Now apply it to your arrays:

```
const result = zipWith(mergerFun)(company_details)(scoreArr);
```

Here is it all in a snippet you can run. I've trimmed your objects to make the snippet a bit clearer.

```js
const companyDetails = [
  {
    type: 'Carrier',
    name: 'Auto',
  },
  {
    type: 'Dealer',
    name: 'Car',
  },
];

const scoreArr = [
  {
    score: 'None'
  },
  {
    score: 'Positive'
  },
];

// zipWith :: ( a -> b -> c ) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
const zipWith = f => xs => ys => xs.map((x, i) => f(x, ys[i]));

// mergerFun :: a -> b -> c
const mergerFun = (a, b) => Object.assign({}, a, b);

// put it all together
const result = zipWith(mergerFun)(companyDetails)(scoreArr);

console.log(result);
```